# WinML does not able to run model with GPU

Tags: windows-machine-learning

WinML LearningModelSession.Evaluate( ) method throws exception with "Unspecified error" message. Is there a way to get more specific information about the error?
[error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWC3k.png)

I'm trying to evaluate a network with 5 dimensions in a GPU with DirectxHighPerformance devicekind setting.
(it works completely fine with a 2D network with 4 parameters)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get more GPU debugging information, you can enable DirectX Control Panel located under `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` or `C:\Windows\System32` and attach your process that is running the machine learning model to it. Provide the full path to the process location. Once you attach your process to the DirectX Control Panel it will be attached until you manually remove it from the list. Just closing the DirectX is not enough to detach the process. With this enabled, you should be able to see more GPU debug information on your output window.

[image]